# Cent OS update to postgresql13-contrib-13.9 causes error postgres_fdw.so undefined symbol: get_rel_all_updated_cols

Tags: postgresql, patch, postgresql-13

I am running CentOS 7.9 and the latest OS updates caused and issue when updating the library `postgresql13-contrib-13.9-1`.

After that update when attempting to create postgres_fdw or use an existing foreign server causes the error:

`ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-13/lib/postgres_fdw.so": /usr/pgsql-13/lib/postgres_fdw.so: undefined symbol: get_rel_all_updated_cols`

Is anyone else seeing this problem, and if so what is the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem after a Debian upgrade. Reboot of the DB seems have helped. Only rebooting the machine itself hasn't.

Comment: Thank you! That did solve the problem. Restarting the PostgreSQL service after the OS update fixes the problem.